# Drive Letter of Devices on UWP Universal Aplication

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-iot-core

```
var myDevices= await Windows.Devices.
    Enumeration.DeviceInformation.
    FindAllAsync(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceClass.PortableStorageDevice);

foreach(var x in myDevices)
{
    string s = string.Format("Kind:{0} Name:{1} Id:{2})",
        x.Kind.tostring(), x.Name, x.Id);
    listbox1.items.add(s);
}
```

this is my example code. is it possible to detect property that I can access drive of myDevices object items ? (something like D:\ or E:\ etc). even I can see drive letters in windows IOT dashboard
(dont know if it makes sense but platform is IOT on rasperry pi3)

Comment: @VMAtm points out you can get such drive name using the path property of subfolder of [RemovableDevices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.knownfolders#Windows_Storage_KnownFolders_RemovableDevices).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found [this](http://lunarfrog.com/blog/external-storage-devices) article about the Windows 8, maybe it is still applicable for your case? Basically it says that you can get the devices as folders in two ways:

- [KnownFolders.RemovableDevices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.knownfolders#Windows_Storage_KnownFolders_RemovableDevices) with [`StorageFolder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefolder) object for each device, which can be used for determine the path
- StorageDevice and DeviceInformation via `Windows.Devices.Portable.StorageDevice.FromId(device.Id);` for each device you've found in `myDevices`

[Access the SD card](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/access-the-sd-card) article on MSDN also mentions the [`StorageFolder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefolder) class as a way to get information about the path.

Side note: you can use the string interpolation to ease the string constructing:

```
string s = $"Kind:{x.Kind} Name:{x.Name} Id:{x.Id})";
```